# gradle configure to get dependency from local directory

Tags: gradle, build, local

I have two gradle projects Alpha and Beta. Beta is dependent on Alpha. Alpha project builds are available in remote repository. So whenever I build Beta project gradle imports the dependencies from remote repo with version property as 1.2.3-+.

Now I build both the projects on my local machine and stored the local Alpha build on /gcache folder with version 1.2.3-999.

If I build Beta project now, still it gets the dependency from the remote repo only even though the local folder has higher build version(999) than the one on remote repo, still the Beta project builds with remore repo version.

What config changes shall I do so that gradle gets the build from local directory?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running a `composite build`.

Try to run your Gradle command like this:

`./gradlew --include-build ../path/to/alpha clean build`

This will build and include the alpha project in your build of beta and replace the external dependency with a project dependency.

More info here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html

Comment: I don't have any build.gradle files in the subfolders to be used for composite build. Can I do it with the single build.gradle file present in ProjectRoot or do I have to create build.gradle for each folder?

Comment: I am not sure. Just give it a try!